# Inherited Arrays with different values Java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I am building my first OOP project and I have a question. I have two classes called `Music` and `Game` which are subclasses of my superclass `Disc`. This superclass has the following member variables:

```
private String title;
private String[] genre;
private String releaseDate;
```

I want my subclasses to inherit these variables and then define their own unique member variables and I have managed to do this successfully with the exception of the `genre`. I want the values for the genres to be different for `Music` and `Game` but I do not understand how I would do this.

These are my fields for Music:

```
private String artist;
private int noOfSongs;
private float duration;
```

Fields for Game:

```
private int[] PEGIRating
private String platform;
```

Do I use setter methods in the subclasses to define the values?

The `Game` class also has an array of PEGI ratings as a variable. If a class has a member field that is an array or list, where should the values for this list be declared and how do you access it from another class?

Thanks

Comment: [Object-Oriented Programming Principles](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html) which is part of Oracle's Java tutorials.

Comment: I would add 2 enums `SongGenre` and `GameGenre` for song genres and game genres respectively. This way you have a well-defined set of genres for each type, which  your abstraction is going to support. It's better than a raw `String[]` array.

    ```enum SongGenre { POP, ROCK; }```
    ```enum GameGenre { SHOOTER, STELTH; }```

`Disc` is quite an abstract entity, `Disc#getGenres()` wouldn't make much sense because genres of music, games, films differ greatly from each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create setter and getter methods of your parent and child classes.
Create class constructor to set values and use super(title,genre,releaseDate) in sub classes to set parent class values.

*If a class has a member field that is an array or list, where should the values for this list be declared and how do you access it from another class?*

You can create your list in your main method and set it while creating object of a class in main method. The setters and getters method used to access variables from another class.